# ViewBinder setViewValue for ListView item leads to multiple CheckBoxes checked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I'm using a `ListView` which has:

1. list item click
2. `CheckBox` click

I can save the cursorPosition by using `view.setTag(cursor.getPosition())` and I can take necessary action on the checked item but when I scroll down, I see several other `CheckBoxes` checked(visual only).
As a work around I tried setting the view description, saving `CheckedBox` view ids in list and then iterate to see if `CheckBox` needs to be shown as checked. But views appear to be reused as I scroll down(same view ids).

How can I only show the actual checked `CheckBoxes`? Code:

```
public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
 public boolean setViewValue(View view, final Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.checkbox:
            view.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
            return true;

            case R.id.....
            .......
        }
```

Used as:

> mySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(myViewBinder);

Comment: Are you using the ViewHolder pattern? Some code would help :)

Comment: Code added. This Viewbinder is used as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have too much experience with the ViewBinder Interface but have you considered using `setChoiceMode()` on the listview ([API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29))? You can set it to [CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) so that android adds the checkboxes for you. You shouldn't need to worry about maintaining the checked items this way.

[API Demo example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List11.html).

Comment: Thats only for CheckedTextView, which I'm not using. I'm using my custom toggleButton. View is pretty complex for CheckedTextView