# Click listener for button in ExpandableListView child view with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-cursoradapter, expandablelistadapter

Here is what I'm working with:  I have an ExpandableListView that uses a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter to fill the view from an SQLite Database.  I'm using custom group and child views, and the group and child views both have buttons in them.  I need to know how I can set a button listener on these buttons so that when the listener is called, I know what row (or cursor id) it came from.  I am able to set a working listener onChildItemDetailsClicked(), but inside the listener I do not know which row corresponds to the button press.  Any ideas?

```
public class MyListActivity extends ExpandableListActivity
{   
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private Cursor mGroupCursor;
private int mGroupIdColumnIndex;
private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDbHelper.openDatabase();

        this.getExpandableListView().setItemsCanFocus(true);
        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() 
    {
        mGroupCursor = mDbHelper.getAllGroupsCursor(); // fills cursor with list of top nodes - groups 
        startManagingCursor(mGroupCursor);

        // Cache the ID column index
        mGroupIdColumnIndex = mGroupCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_ID);

        // Set up our adapter
        String[] groupCols = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.COL_TITLE, DatabaseHelper.COL_TEXT };
        int[] groupViews = new int[] { R.id.group_title, R.id.group_text };
        String[] childCols = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COL_TEXT };
        int[] childViews = new int[] {R.id.child_text };

        mAdapter = new ExamineActivityAdapter(this, mGroupCursor, 
            R.layout.mylist_group_row, groupCols, groupViews,
            R.layout.mylise_child_row, childCols, childViews);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class MyListActivityAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter
    {   
        public MyListActivityAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, 
            int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, 
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) 
        {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        }

        // returns cursor with subitems for given group cursor
        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) 
        {
        Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper.getChildrenCursorForGroup(groupCursor.getInt(mGroupIdColumnIndex));
        startManagingCursor(childCursor);
            return childCursor;
        }
    }

    public void onChildItemDetailsClicked(View v)
    {       
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "child detail clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Group View:

```
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/group_title"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:singleLine="true"
       />

       <Button 
           android:id="@+id/group_detail_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:lines="1"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:text="@string/button_detail"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@id/group_title"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/group_text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:ellipsize="marquee"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:lines="3"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/group_detail_button"
           android:layout_alignTop="@id/group_detail_button"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Child View:

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/child_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/child_detail_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:lines="1"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:text="@string/button_detail"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:onClick="onChildItemDetailsClicked"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_below="@id/child_text"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/child_check"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/child_text"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/child_detail_button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/child_detail_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ViewBinder` to your adapter and there, add listener for buttons. 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534577/viewbinder-setviewvalue-for-list-item-leads-to-multiple-checkbox-checked) can help.

Comment: Based on @Keyhan's help, I got this to work by adding a class `MyViewBinder implements android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.ViewBinder`.  I override `public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)`, and within that method I set up my views and use `view.setTag(myId)` to associate an id with the view.

Comment: i want to same but i am using BaseExpandableListAdapter (as i don't want to use db or cursor)..please tell me how this can be done ?

Comment: I think this might help: http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.apitest/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html